# How to get a keyCode for *focus* HostListener

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive, keycode

I have a directive which set a focus style to the active element in the HTML DOM.
For now, it's work fine but I need to do this logic only when I press the tab button.

```
@HostListener('focus', ["$event"])
    onFocus(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log("Focus called from HostListener");
    }
```

And I don't see in the *event* object the keyCode property.

How can I get this keyCode for this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input (keydown.Tab)="onKey($event)">
```

TS:

```
onKey(event:any){
 //Do logic
}
```

Comment: It's ok, but I need the detect keyCode on the @HostListener('focus', ["$event"]). If it's possible.

Comment: i dont know how u want to achieve this, this event is when you focus, not when you press the key, they are 2 differents events, and cant combine in the same event detection. I will edit my answer with keytab detection.

Answer (score 1):

Simple put it in your html:

```
<input (focus)="isFocused($event)" />
```

Or when unfocus:

```
<input (blur)="onBlur($event)" />
```

If you want to detect the tab:

```
<input (input)="onInput($event)" />
```

Of course you can combine them both. But if you tab into the input the **(focus)** will trigger.

Comment: simple and brilliant